# kind of web pages in android webview

Tags: android, webview

I am using a webview to display a webpage.
But the webview loads only websites like google, yahoo.
It doesn even load a wikipedia pages.
Any help will be appreciated
Ty
Abhi

EDIT code from comment:

```
webview= new WebView(this);
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webview.loadUrl("arthistoryguide.com/Mona_Lisa.aspx";);
```

Comment: Please add your code where you try to load the webpage. It is easier to see where things might be wrong.

Comment: webview= new WebView(this); webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);webview.loadUrl("http://www.arthistoryguide.com/Mona_Lisa.aspx");
this code works fine if i open google or yahoo website but not others

Comment: i'm not sure whetehr android browser capable of handling .aspx pages. I've tried .php pages it works.

Comment: try adding http:// to the url.

Comment: You have a semicolon to much in your code, or is that just a typo? webview.loadUrl("arthistoryguide.com/Mona_Lisa.aspx";);

Comment: sorry it is a typo..http://www.arthistoryguide.com/Mona_Lisa.aspx is the url

Answer (score 0):

You may wanna try the mobile url "en.m.wikipedia.org/" than just http://en.wikpedia.org